# does the doc folder contain only documentation?

Tags: documentation, distributions

I'm trying to get rid of some junk on my hard drive and want to make sure I don't delete anything vital, so it's probably a dumb question.

In my latex tree there is the texmf-dist/doc folder which is over  2GB in size. Does that contain only documentation? I presume so, and given the fact that I usually look up documentation online I'd like to delete it.

Comment: Note that while it is perfectly OK to delete anything on your own machine, you should be careful not to give such a cut down installation to anyone else, the licences on many components of the tex distribution (whether LPPL or GPL or other) often state that source and/or documentation should be distributed with the code.

Comment: Note that it is possible to install TeX without documentation, as an installation option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's specified by the [TeX Directory Structure](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/tds/tds.html) (TDS):

> 3 Top-level directories
>
> - ...
> - `doc`  for user documentation

So, if there would be anything else than documentation, it would be in the wrong place.

Though I consider documentation as very important, I understand that you just change the way of access to online. Just note, that online documentation might not match the versions you have locally installed.

A good source for you: [TeXdoc.net](http://texdoc.net), based on TeX Live 2012 and regularly updated. It even offers a "quick search" you could use in the search field at the top right of the Firefox browser.

Comment: that's quite an authoritative answer (I was expecting things like: "sure man, go ahead"). thanks :)

Comment: It might be worth cautioning that sometimes 'demo' files go in `doc`, for example 'test' `.bib` files can end up there. This may or may not be important.

Answer (score 5):

Please interpret this answer as having the best possible intention of helping you. :)

Although this doesn't tell you how to do what you've asked for, and although I don't have any idea about your personal "disk space circumstances", I'd strongly recommend pursuing a different solution.

One option is simply "get more disk space"; I accept this may not be an option in your case.

For another approach, you may care to try a tool like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) (for Windows -- I have no experience of doing this on Linux, though KDE has KDirStat, I think). This will allow you to find the "hot spots" quickly.

Experience suggests that micro-managing space by trimming lots of small files doesn't usually give you a good return for your time, when compared with offloading, say, three films onto an external drive.

My current TeXLive `texmf-dist/doc` subtree is 1.25 Gb; *I* think it's worth every byte to have it at my fingertips.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. Unfortunately my storage is very very limited and I do not have a single movie, photo or song on my computer! :P

Comment: OK, I understand your predicament :)

Answer (score 2):

The post is old, but for actual readers: as far I know, any package update will reinstall them, so deactivate this in your manager.
For example "sudo tlmgr option docfiles 0", or option it out in preferences of TexLive Utility.